# Cannot convert set( ) to Excel

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, openpyxl, xlrd

I would like to know how to write in an excel file using a python dictionary. (`xlrd` and `openpyxl`)

I created a Japanese-English dictionary in an excel file and stored them as a dictionary in python as follows:

```
    d = {}
    for i in range(inputWs.nrows):
        cell_value_id = inputWs.cell(i,0).value
        cell_value_class1 = inputWs.cell(i,1).value
        d[cell_value_id] = {cell_value_class1}
```

What I am trying to do is to read `menuWs`, a list of Japanese words in an excel file, then write English words corresponding to each Japanese word using the dictionary as follows:

```
    for j in range(1, translatedWs.max_row + 1):
        print(d.get(menuWs.cell_value(j, 0)))
        translatedWs.cell(row = j, column = 2, value = d.get(menuWs.cell_value(j, 0)))
```

However, I get an error *Cannot convert set([u'English']) to Excel*. I have a very poor experience in coding and this is my first time using python. I've been stuck for this for a couple of days already, so I would very much appreciate it if you could help me out with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign `cell_value_class1` to your dictionary, you do not need the additional curly braces `{}` - by using this notation you are creating a [set](https://snakify.org/en/lessons/sets/).

If you add this line directly below you will see...

```
d = {}
    for i in range(inputWs.nrows):
        cell_value_id = inputWs.cell(i,0).value
        cell_value_class1 = inputWs.cell(i,1).value
        d[cell_value_id] = {cell_value_class1}
        print(type(d[cell_value_id]))      # <-- this will show <class 'set'>
```

What I think you want to do, is just add the value directly to your dictionary.
Remove those `{}` like so...

`d[cell_value_id] = cell_value_class1`

You are now adding an `int` or `str` or whatever type `cell_value_class1` is, which I think is what you are trying to do.